# Azure Web Role MVC5 does not start in integrated mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-roles

After upgrade my Azure Web role project with MVC4 and SDK 2.2 to SDK 2.4 and MVC5, starts the application only in the emulator, but not in the cloud (empty page or "Page can not displayed").

After remote login on the VM and changing the application pool mode from integrated to classic, works the page also with the new settings. Changes of the handler settings in the web.config were unsuccessful.

Current web.config with MVC5 and SDK2.4:

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules>
  <add name="PageSpeedModule" type="CheckMyBus.Web.Frontend.Modules.ProtectionModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
<handlers>
<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" /><remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
</handlers>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
<httpCompression>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
  </dynamicTypes>
</httpCompression>
<staticContent>
  <clientCache setEtag="false" />
</staticContent>
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough" />
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RemoveIllegalCharacters">
      <match url="(.*)(&quot;|%22)(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}{R:3}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RemoveTrailingSlashRule1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)/$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Remove Version from static files" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(styles|scripts|images)/(.+);v[0-9]+\.(css|js|gif|png|jpg|ico)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/{R:2}.{R:3}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="EnforceLowerCase" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Last web.config works fine with MVC4 and SDK2.2:

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules>
  <add name="PageSpeedModule" type="CheckMyBus.Web.Frontend.Modules.ProtectionModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />

      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" /><remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" /><remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" /><add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" /></handlers>
  <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
<httpCompression>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
  </dynamicTypes>
</httpCompression>
<staticContent>
  <clientCache setEtag="false" />
</staticContent>
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough" />
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RemoveIllegalCharacters">
      <match url="(.*)(&quot;|%22)(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}{R:3}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RemoveTrailingSlashRule1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)/$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Remove Version from static files" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(styles|scripts|images)/(.+);v[0-9]+\.(css|js|gif|png|jpg|ico)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/{R:2}.{R:3}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="EnforceLowerCase" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Can everyone help me?

Comment: check your event log of the Web Role to see errors or warnings from the .NET framework.

Comment: The event log contains no error and warnings.

Comment: Problem solved! The nuget update for SDK 2.4 has not updated the web.config in the views folder. There has contains references of the previous MVC dlls version.

Answer (score 0):

Having upgraded to MVC5 manually I didn't realize that the pages-clause in the Views weg.config had THREE references to System.Web.Mvc. That made the web role recyle forever.

Fixing this solved my rcycling issue.